# Using drag drop and rotation on a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop, rotation

Hello i need u put in a rotation as well as drag and drop on a single div.. I tried the following code but only when the form loads i am able to drag and drop after which it gets disabled. I am able to rotate at any point but unable to drag and drop... Please Help!!

```
 <style>
  #mainTarget{
width:300px; 
height:200px; 
position:relative;
top:100px; 
left:25%
}

.mainTarget{position:absolute; width:300px; height:200px;}

#target{
position:absolute;
height:20px;
width:20px;
background:url(http://files.softicons.com/download/system-icons/human-o2-icons-by-oliver-scholtz/png/128x128/actions/object-rotate-left.png) no-repeat top center #ffffff;
background-size:100%;
cursor:pointer; 
z-index:1; 
top:0; 
right:0;    
}
 #target1{
position:absolute;
height:20px;
width:20px;
background:url(http://files.softicons.com/download/system-icons/human-o2-icons-by-oliver-scholtz/png/128x128/actions/object-rotate-left.png) no-repeat top center #ffffff;
background-size:100%;
cursor:pointer; 
z-index:1; 
bottom:0; 
left:0;    
}

  #mainTarget1{

width:320px; 
height:200px; 
position:relative;

}

  .mainTarget1{position:absolute; width:300px; height:200px;}
</style>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js">                            </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
 <body>

    <p>degrees</p>
   <span> rotate</span>
  <input type="text" id="style" name="style" /> 
 <div id="mainTarget">  
 <div >
 <img src="http://myreaxns.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/priyanka-chopra-  image.jpg" width="300" class="mainTarget" />


<div id="target">&nbsp;</div></div>
<div id="mainTarget1">
<img src="http://myreaxns.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/priyanka-chopra-image.jpg" width="300" class="mainTarget1" />
<div id="target1">&nbsp;</div>

</div>

</div>
```

```
<script>
  var dragging = false;
  $(function() {
var target = $('#target');  
var target1 = $('#target1');
var mainTarget = $('#mainTarget');
var mainTarget1 = $('#mainTarget1');
var rad = mainTarget.width()/2;
var elOfs = mainTarget.offset();
var elPos = {
   x: elOfs.left,
   y: elOfs.top
};
target.mousedown(function() {
    $('#mainTarget').draggable({ disabled: true });
    dragging = true;
});
$(document).mouseup(function(a) {
var mPos = {
    x: a.pageX-elPos.x,
    y: a.pageY-elPos.y
  };
  var getAtan = Math.atan2(mPos.x-rad, mPos.y-rad);
  var getDeg = -getAtan/(Math.PI/180) + 135;  //135 = (180deg-45deg)


  $('span').text(getDeg);

    if (dragging) {
        mainTarget.css({transform: 'rotate(' + getDeg + 'deg)'});
    }
    $('#mainTarget').draggable({ disabled: true });
    dragging = false;
});

$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
  var mPos = {
    x: e.pageX-elPos.x,
    y: e.pageY-elPos.y
  };
  var getAtan = Math.atan2(mPos.x-rad, mPos.y-rad);
  var getDeg = -getAtan/(Math.PI/180) + 135;  //135 = (180deg-45deg)


  $('p').text(getDeg);
  var style_position = $("#mainTarget").attr("style");

        $("#style").val(style_position);
    if (dragging) {
        mainTarget.css({transform: 'rotate(' + getDeg + 'deg)'});
    }

});
$('#mainTarget').draggable();
$('#target1').mousemove(function() {
$('#mainTarget').draggable();
$("#mainTarget").attr("class","ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle ui-draggable-dragging");


});
$('#target1').mousedown(function() {

$('#mainTarget').draggable();
$("#mainTarget").attr("class","ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle ui-draggable-dragging");

});
$('#target1').mouseup(function() {

$("#mainTarget").attr("class","ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle ui-draggable-dragging");
$('#mainTarget').draggable();
 //dragging = true;
});

});

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You better rewrite the js. Start over and define two containers for the image - one to be applied rotation on and one to be applied translation on. Also figure if you are going to use jQueryUI draggable or not and stick to that. 
Here is a simple sample ( not refined at all ) using only event mouse position from your code and no jQuery UI and incorporating the idea of two containers:

```
 var dragging = false;
 var rotating = false;
 var target = $('#target');
 var target1 = $('#target1');
 var mainTarget = $('#mainTarget');
 var mainTarget1 = $('#mainTarget1');
 var rad = mainTarget.width() / 2;
 var elOfs = $('.mainTarget').offset();
 var elPos = {
      x: elOfs.left,
      y: elOfs.top
 }
 target.mousedown(function () {;
      dragging = false;
      rotating = true;
 });
 $(".mainTarget").mousedown(function (a) {
      dragging = true;
      rotating = false;
 });
 $(document).mouseup(function (a) {
      dragging = (dragging) ? false : dragging;
      rotating = (rotating) ? false : rotating;     
 });
 $(document).mousemove(function (e) {
      var mPos = {
          x: e.pageX - elPos.x,
          y: e.pageY - elPos.y
      };
      var getAtan = Math.atan2(mPos.x - rad, mPos.y - rad);
      var getDeg = -getAtan / (Math.PI / 180) + 135; //135 = (180deg-45deg)
      $('p').text(getDeg);
      var style_position = $("#mainTarget").attr("style");     
      $("#style").val(style_position);
      if (rotating) {
          $('#rotate').css({
              transform: 'rotate(' + getDeg + 'deg)'
          });
      }
      if (dragging) {
          mainTarget.css({
              transform: 'translate(' + mPos.x + 'px,' + mPos.y + 'px)'
          });
      }

 });
```

And here is the html:

```
<p>degrees</p> <span> rotate</span>

<input type="text" id="style" name="style" />
<div id="mainTarget">
    <div id="rotate">
        <img src="http://www.joomlaworks.net/images/demos/galleries/abstract/7.jpg" width="300" class="mainTarget" />
        <div id="target">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and one new CSS Rule:

```
#rotate{
    position:relative;
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
}
```

[here is the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mzografski/0duzx033/)